# GCC vs. Clang on the lifetime of temporary bound to an rvalue reference of another temporary

Tags: c++, visual-c++, g++, c++20, clang++

I want to figure out the lifetime of a temporary object `S{}` bound to an rvalue reference inside `struct wrap<T>`.
`wrap<T>::f()` is a function that potentially interacts with the temporary; therefore, `S{}` must be alive when `wrap<T>::f()` is called.
I consider two cases: (1) `wrap{S{}}.f();` and (2) `auto w = wrap{S{}}; w.f();`.
I am confident the first case should not result in any dangling references because `S{}` is destroyed only after the entire expression is evaluated.
However, for the second case, I am not really certain.
I hypothesized that the lifetime of the temporary should match the lifetime of `w`.
To test my hypothesis, I wrote the following code snippet (also available on [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/db79vEeMx)):

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct S {
    S() { puts("S::S()"); }
    ~S() { puts("S::~S()"); }
};

template <typename T>
struct wrap {
    T &&t;

    void f() {
        puts("wrap<T>::f()");
    }
};

template <typename T>
wrap(T &&) -> wrap<T>;

int main() {
    #if defined(_MSC_VER)
    puts("msvc");
    #elif defined(__clang__)
    puts("clang");
    #else // gnu
    puts("gcc");
    #endif

    puts("== first ==");
    wrap{S{}}.f();
    
    puts("== second ==");
    auto w = wrap{S{}};
    w.f();
    return 0;
}
```

It seems like there is a disagreement among the compilers:

For `x86-64 GCC 12.1` with `-std=c++20`:

```
gcc
== first ==
S::S()
wrap<T>::f()
S::~S()
== second ==
S::S()
wrap<T>::f()
S::~S()
```

For `x86-64 clang (trunk)` with `-std=c++20`:

```
clang
== first ==
S::S()
wrap<T>::f()
S::~S()
== second ==
S::S()
S::~S()
wrap<T>::f()
```

And, finally, `x64 msvc v19.latest` with `/std:c++latest`:

```
msvc
== first ==
S::S()
wrap<T>::f()
S::~S()
== second ==
S::S()
wrap<T>::f()
S::~S()
```

GCC and MSVC extend the lifetime of the temporary object, whereas clang does not. Which behavior is correct according to the standard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

clang is incorrect: both examples are valid and within lifetimes.

The rule is that temporaries bound to references live as long as the reference (with some exceptions that don't apply here). Note that:

```cpp
auto w = wrap{S{}};
```

is exactly equivalent to:

```cpp
wrap<S> w{S{}};
```

And list-initialization directly binds (as opposed to parentheses).

---

There is even an example in the standard that is basically exactly this, in [[class.temporary]](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.temporary#example-4):

```cpp
struct S {
  const int& m;
};
const S& s = S{1};  // both S and int temporaries have lifetime of s
```

Comment: Thank you. I accepted this as an answer; however, I noticed a little problem. If we change the code as `auto &&w = wrap{S{}};`, clang produces the expected output. Note that in the original code, it is not bound to a reference, but rather copied. What does the standard say about it? This is not exactly the same example that you posted.

Comment: @jnbrq-CanberkSönmez `S{}` has the lifetime of `wrap{..}`, and then `wrap{..}` has the lifetime of `w`.

Comment: What if we return `wrap{S{}}` by value from a function then? `auto f() { return wrap{S{}}; }`. With RVO, `auto w = f();` is basically the same thing as `auto w = wrap{S{}};` except that the compiler cannot keep `S{}` alive after `f` returns. The lifetime boundary should be drawn somewhere, copies seem to be a reasonable choice.

Comment: @jnbrq-CanberkSönmez But it's not basically the same thing, and `auto w = f();` isn't a copy.

Comment: Thank you. So, do you mean that `auto w = f();` and `auto w = wrap{S{}};` should have the same effect? Maybe. Regardless, I will probably not rely on GCC/MSVC behavior, because that effect is gone if I add a constructor `template <typename TT> wrap(TT &&tt): t{std::forward<TT>(tt)} { }` instead of using aggregate initialization. (now, the temporary is destroyed before `f` is called)